# Program for selecting the operator

Tags: java, string, char, operators

```
    import java.util.*;
class calc123
{
    public static void main()
    {
        int a,b,c;
        char a1;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter first number");
        a=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter second number");
        b=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the operator");
        a1=sc.next().charAt(0);
        if(a1="+")
        System.out.println(a+b);
        else if(a1="-")
        System.out.println(a-b);
        else if(a1="/")
        System.out.println(a/b);
        else if(a1="*")
        System.out.println(a*b);
        else if(a1="%")
        System.out.println(a%b);
        else
        System.out.println("Invalid Operator");
    }
}
```

It is facing the problem that (a1="+") is

```
incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to char.
```

Comment: still can't execute the program

Comment: Sotirios Delimanolis has just edited question.No one provides solution in edited question.Also go through http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

(a1="+") will not return true or false , it will return "+" !, please improve your basic knowledge of Java.Also note that a1 is of char type, while "+" is of String.

Comment: so what should I use instead of "+"

Comment: Use a1=='+' , and also you can use switch case rather if else here.
== operator compares values of both operand while = operator assigns value to the left side operand and returns the same !

Comment: but I have to use only if else